# Python Selenium Detection Error?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi i've been trying to learn selenium.

The problem i am having is that an element isn't being detected. The html code i am working with is highlighted right here https://gyazo.com/a76608d4c4e9fc3bd29412436604c173. That line of code stopped my program and gave me the error https://gyazo.com/72fc72e6488578c9c2a50b71311602c5.

The code i am using to detect for the textarea class is

```
comment=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='comment-form no-border-top']/div/*[1]") or driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='comment-form']/div/*[1]")
```

because sometimes it switches between comment-form no border and comment form.

My idea is to use a conditional assignment operator check for example if(comment!=none): do something, but to my understanding python doesn't allow this.

any suggestions on what to do and whether my xpath is a reliable method?

Comment: Please add the HTML code and the error messages as text to your question, not as linked images. Also I have edited the code in your question to what I think you intended.

Comment: If you're actually using `comment = foo() or bar()`, then `comment` will be the result of a boolean `or` between the [truthy](https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs258/truthiness-in-python) values of the two function calls.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you're trying to solve is actually conditional assignment, there are two different things you might want to know.

The first is that you *can* do:

> if(comment!=none)

you just have to do it like this:

```
comment = Foo()
if comment is None:
    comment = Bar()
```

Second, maybe you want to *try* assigning `comment` if the first call throws an error rather than just being `None`. If so, try using `try`!

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
   comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='comment-form no-border-top']/div/*[1]")
except NoSuchElementException:
   comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='comment-form']/div/*[1]")
```